# Быстрый сигнатурный поиск по файлу

Tags: c#, поиск, алгоритм, файлы

Приветствую всех.
Есть байты на точке входа в программу **`60 68 A1 E2 C3 F5 B8 B6 75 C4 35 FF 10`**
и есть сигнатура вида **`6068::::::::B8::::::::FF10`**. Вопрос заключается в том, как можно реализовать быстрый поиск по этой маске.

Вот пример кода, как я это реализовывал, но чем будет больше сигнатур в базе, тем меньше будет скорость работы.

```
            for (int k = 0; k < SignatureElement.InnerText.Length; k++)
            {
                if (SignatureElement.InnerText[k].ToString() != ":")
                {
                if (InFile[k].ToString() != SignatureElement.InnerText[k].ToString())
                    {
                        ++Error;
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Comment: представить набор в виде двоичного дерева и использовать соответствующие алгоритмы обхода дерева.

Answer (score 4):

Первое, что приходит в голову - разделить все сигнатуры на группы. Группы выделять по первым 4 байтам (Если у двух сигнатур одинаковое начало - выделяем их в одну группу). Теперь проходим по файлу считывая по 4 байта (на самом то деле читать 4 байта будем только первый раз, потом первый удаляем, 3 байта смещаем влево и один подчитываем с файла). Если очередные 4 байта совпали с одной из групп, то начинаем углубляться внутрь группы. Если совпадений нет - идем далее.
Как углубляться внутрь? Запоминаем текущее положение в файле и повторяем вышеуказанное для группы (группу можно поделить на свои подгруппы). Текущее положение запоминается для того, что бы если сигнатура не совпала полностью, знать, куда откатиться.

Идеализируем идею - все сигнатуры грузим в одно дерево. При этом не обязательно загружать каждую сигнатуру полностью - можно только начало.

Тут нужно хорошо подумать и сделать оценки, может быть будет выгодно брать не по 4 байта, а по одному или двум.  А может и 16.

Алгоритм будет медленно работать только в том случае, если в файле есть много кусков, которые совпадает с сигнатурами, кроме последнего байта.

Для дальнейших улучшений - почитайте Кнута.